# How can I show the dates of this angular calendar properly?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

So, I am a newbie at Angular and I wanted to start learning angular by trying to develop a calendar. While doing researches I have stumbled across an article, which explains this issue. However, apparently I found a mistake in the code, but I don't know how to fix it. Maybe some of you can explain me what is wrong with the code.

Now coming to the bug, I noticed that every april of the calendar doesn't show the days properly. [image]

Here are the links of the stackblitz and the article.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-min-calendar?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcalendar%2Fcalendar.component.html

https://medium.com/allenhwkim/angular-build-a-calendar-in-50-lines-f813f0a04c3b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the daylight saving time changing in March. Here's a fixed version which translates the dates by a couple of hours to avoid the DST issue:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-min-calendar-tzztcm